# puppet module not getting installed in agent

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install a puppet module in master and the agent node. The installation on the master is successful, the new module is visible in module list. Then I changed the site.pp file and included the new module. After that I ran the `puppet agent -t` command on the agent and expected the module to be installed in the agent. The command is running without any issues but the module is not getting installed.

Following is the sequence of steps which were executed on master:

1. `puppet module install puppetlabs-ntp --version 6.2.0`
2. `puppet agent -t`
3. `puppet module list`

Output:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
├── puppetlabs-ntp (v6.2.0)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.17.1)
```

4. Updated site.pp file as follows:

Content:

```
node default {
  include ntp
}
```

And the following is the steps executed on agent:

5. `puppet agent -t`
6. `puppet module list`

Output:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.17.1)
```

Have even compared the output of puppet agent -t --debug from both master and agent but did not see any specific errors which might be causing this issue.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how Puppet works. If everything is set up correctly, the result you should expect when you run `puppet agent -t` on the agent is for Puppet on that node to configure the ntp service for you. It will not transfer the ntp module to the agent. The Puppet code itself is supposed to remain on the master.